# Регулярные выражения разделить дефисом слово с цифрами

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как на javascript при помощи регулярного выражения разделить дефисом слово с цифрами ? 
К примеру: "1пример1" на "1-пример-1".

Comment: уточни, пожалуйста, язык программирования

Comment: написать на javascript

Comment: `'1gfds2gfdw6hgfds7777'.replace(/(\D)(\d+)/g, '$1-$2').replace(/(\d+)(\D)/g, '$1-$2')`. уверен, что можно это сделать эффективнее

Comment: @nörbörnën, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 2):

## Решение 1

Чтобы вставить дефис между цифрой и латинской/русской буквой достаточно использовать

```
s = s.replace(/(\d)(?=[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])|([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])(?=\d)/g, '$1$2-');
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/6ryJuh/1).

**Подробности**

- `(\d)(?=[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])` - любая цифра захватывается в группу №1 (`(\d)`) и производится проверка следующего символа с помощью блока предварительного просмотра вперёд `(?=[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])`. Если это буква русского или английского алфавита, совпадение возвращается, в противном случае совпадения нет  (т.е. ищем цифру, затем букву)
- `|` - или
- `([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])(?=\d)` - то же, что и в первом случае, только буквенный и цифровой шаблоны переставлены (т.е. ищем букву, затем цифру).

Так как захватывающие подмаски (группы) помещают текст в буфер совпадения, в шаблоне замены нужно указать обратные ссылки на эти группы (чтобы цифры и буквы не были удалены), а затем символ `-`.

## Решение 2 (полная поддержка Юникода с ECMAScript 2018)

Если браузер поддерживает стандарт ECMAScript 2018, который поддерживает блоки просмотра назад и категории Юникода в регулярных выражениях, то решение будет более точным:

```
s = s.replace(/(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})|(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)/gu, '-');
```

См. [демо этого регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/6ryJuh/2). Обратите внимание на то, что в данном регулярном выражении модификатор `u` необходим.

**Подробности**

- `(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})` - блок предварительного просмотра назад `(?<=\d)` возвращает совпадение в такой позиции в строке, перед которой стоит цифра, а блок предварительного просмотра вперёд `(?=\p{L})` возвращает совпадение, если сразу после цифры идёт любая буква Юникода. Т.е. ищем позицию в строке между цифрой и буквой.
- `|` - или
- `(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)` - аналогично первой альтернативе, только тут мы ищем позицию в строке между буквой и цифрой.

Так как блоки просмотра не помещают текст в буфер совпадения, в шаблоне замены нужно указать лишь символ `-`.

## Решение 3 (полная поддержка Юникода с *XRegExp*)

Если нужна точность второго выражения во всех реализациях JavaScript, используйте библиотеку [`XRegExp`](http://xregexp.com/):

```
s = XRegExp.replace(s, XRegExp("(\\d)(?=\\p{L})|(\\p{L})(?=\\d)", "gu"), "$1$2-");
```

Двойные обратные слеши необходимы, так как шаблон объявляется в виде строкового литерала (где для задания знака `\` необходимо использование `"\\"`).

Демо-код всех трёх решений на JavaScript (второй работает в последних версиях Chrome и других совместимых с ECMAScript 2018 средах):

```js
var s = "1пример1";
// Решение 1
console.log(s.replace(/(\d)(?=[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])|([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])(?=\d)/g, '$1$2-'));
// Решение 2 (не работает в средах, не поддерживающих стандарт ECMAScript 2018)
console.log(s.replace(/(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})|(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)/gu, '-'));
// Решение 3
console.log(XRegExp.replace(s, XRegExp("(\\d)(?=\\p{L})|(\\p{L})(?=\\d)", "gu"), "$1$2-"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```